# Unable to download .apk file programmatically

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to download an android apk file by clicking on update button. I have used Async Task to carry out the process in background.

A new file `ec.apk` is created in phone's Sdcard/Download but file is not downloaded. File size = 0 bytes. I also used `fos.flush()` method to make buffer empty.

```
if(v==btUpdate){
  UpdateApp atualizaApp=new UpdateApp();
  atualizaApp.setContext(getApplicationContext());
  atualizaApp.execute("http://mobileapp.abc.org/e-mobapps/ec.apk");
}


public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
  private Context context;
  public void setContext(Context contextf){
    context = contextf;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
      HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      c.setRequestMethod("GET");
      c.setDoOutput(true);
      c.connect();


      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/");
      file.mkdirs();
      File outputFile = new File(file, "ec.apk");
      if(outputFile.exists()){
        outputFile.delete();
      }
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

      InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int len1 = 0;
      while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
      }
      fos.close();
      is.close();

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/" + "ec.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
      context.startActivity(intent);


    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: do you have the WRITE permission?

Comment: yes i granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: At the least log the value of len1 each time through the while loop, and perhaps it cumulative total as well.  That should help you distinguish between not getting any data, and not managing to write it.

Answer (score 0):

> I also used fos.flush() method to make buffer empty.

That is insufficient if you are trying to use the file immediately, as you appear to be doing here. You also need to call `getFD().sync()` on the `FileOutputStream` before `close()`, so the OS buffers get flushed to disk. See [this Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html) post for more.

Beyond that, you might wish to use the three-parameter `e()` method, so you get the full stack trace, then double-check LogCat to see if you are encountering any problems.